# Associated Delete in CakePHP 2.5.4

Tags: php, cakephp

I have 2 entities in the database Element and Section.

1 section has 0-N elements so in the element table I have a foreign key

```
CONSTRAINT `elements_sections` FOREIGN KEY (`section_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Element Model .php has this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
        'Section' => array(
            'className' => 'Section',
            'foreignKey' => 'section_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

In the Section model I have:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Element' => array(
        'className' => 'Element',
        'foreignKey' => 'section_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

All this code looks good, however, when I delete an element of the section with ID=X, if there's an element (in any other section) with ID=X that element is deleted too. This is the code I am using in my whole aplication but only fails here. $this->data is the Element object.

```
$this->Element->delete($this->data)
```

A detailed example:

Section 20 -> Element 400
Section 3 -> Element 20

If I delete the element 400, the Element 20 is deleted too.

I guess that I am missing a configuration parameter or some.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For somebody that can face the same problem this could help:

Model::delete() can delete multiple records.

```
[
    'id' => 1,
    'category_id' => 3,
    'price' => 10000,
]
```

Will generate

```
DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN (1, 3, 10000).
```